# How can you put single spaces into a string of characters in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, permutation

I am still a beginner in C# and I know there is a method that can be used to do this but I can't seem to find it online.

I have a function that permutates a word

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] list = "a b c d".Split();
    foreach (string[] permutation in Permutations<string>.AllFor(list))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", permutation));
    }
}
```

However it only works with words that are broken up. (eg. "a b c d" ) Since  that is not really a practical way to ask a user for input, I want to find a way to take a word from the user (an unbroken word like "hello" ) and break it up for the function to understand. Eg. form the input word of the use "happy" to a spaced word for the program to understand = "h a p p y"

I tried this code:

```
//splits the word into an array
string[] arr = name.Split();

//splits the array with spaces to enter into the program
name = string.Join(" ",arr);

arr = name.Split();
```

But it just ends up coming out unbroken anyway. Can someone tell me the easiest way to do this?

Just to mention I am still a beginner in C# and programming in total I might not understand some of the higher level concepts. I have been through some answers on this website and I have seen some answers that I don't understand at all.

Comment: Agreed with the above - a string is a collection of characters, so name[0] would be 'a' in your example.

Comment: can you just give an example of a sample input and desired output ?

Comment: i actually want the user to put in an input unbroken like = "Happy" and breaks it up into "H a p p y" with the spaces not the other way around. :)

Comment: ahh, sorry then.I'm really overthinking this because I'm so tired :/ anyway, I updated my answer I hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    char[] array=input.ToArray();
string val="";
for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
{
val+=array[i]+" ";
}
```

this will give you a string   with spaces like you wanted **Val**
create an array with the string length

```
string[] strarray=new string[val.Length];


   for(int i=0;i<strarray.Length;i++)
{
strarray[i]=val.Substring(i,len); //**i** is for string index,,,**len** string length in each index
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch but how would i change the output from this into an array without using "output.Split()" because I found out that while tweaking the code the ".Split()" method gets rid of the spaces.

Comment: you want the array with or with out the spaces?

Comment: i want the array with spaces

Answer (score 1):

You just need to separate each character and then concatenate them with a space:

This is the *simplest* way:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

var output = string.Join<char>(" ", userInput);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: thanks a bunch but how would i change the output from this into an array without using "output.Split()" because I found out that while tweaking the code the ".Split()" method gets rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the string to convert it to an array, and then  use `Join`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

public class Program{
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string v = "hello";

        // Convert into the a string array, the old-fashioned way.
        string[] name = new string[v.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
        name[i] = v[i] + ""; 


        string feedToPermutationFunction = string.Join(" ",name));
        // Feed the above string into your permutation code.
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I look at that, your solution is correct but includes a lot of redundant code.why not just `string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray())` ?

Comment: Forgive my noobness :D

Comment: @Selman22, `input.ToCharArray()` returns a `char` array, while `string.join()` requires a `string[]`.

Comment: thanks a bunch but how would i change the output from this into an array without using "output.Split()" because I found out that while tweaking the code the ".Split()" method gets rid of the spaces.

Comment: @luid, which spaces are you trying to keep and which are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: The code as written will give you `feedToPermutationFunction = 'h e l l o'.

Comment: @merlin2011 no `string.Join` has an overload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Selman22, Good to know for my own reference. Thank you. However, I'll leave this answer as is, because it is simpler by virtue of having no generic methods. :P

Comment: @merlin2011 i am trying to keep the spaces in between the letters like  "H_e_l_l_o" the dashes are the spaces that i am trying to keep but the ".Split()" method just joins them all together again when i try to make it into an array.

Comment: @Luid, Please clarify exactly which call to `Split()` you are referring to. Do you want the letters by themselves in an array, or do you want them joined together into a single string with no spaces between each letter?

Comment: @merlin2011 i want them joined together in an array that also includes the spaces for example an array like name[] would have name[0] == "H", name[1] == " ", name[2] == "E" ... etc..